Traefik for RabbitMQ unable to connect
Docker is running on a Linux server with Traefik configured. I have configured Traefik running as proxy for the UI interface and I also want as a proxy for the TCP ports 5671 and 5672 but I can't seem to work out how to configure it. I'm using .yml files instead instead of labels for the configuration, I find it easier to setup and debug.
This is the static traefik.yml configuration:
api:
  dashboard: true

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"
  amqp:
    address: ":5672"
  amqps:
    address: ":5671"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: "/etc/traefik/dynamic"

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: webmaster@example.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http

log:
  filePath: "/var/logs/traefik/traefik.log"

I've setup the amqp and amqps entrypoints for RabbitMQ for the ports 5671 and 5672. The docker-compose.yml file for the RabbitMQ container is this:
services:
  pubsub:
    image: bitnami/rabbitmq:3.13.7
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_VHOST: ${RABBITMQ_VHOST}
      RABBITMQ_PORT: ${RABBITMQ_PORT:-5672}
      RABBITMQ_USERNAME: ${RABBITMQ_USERNAME}
      RABBITMQ_PASSWORD: ${RABBITMQ_PASSWORD}
      RABBITMQ_PLUGINS: rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_shovel,rabbitmq_shovel_management,rabbitmq_prometheus
      RABBITMQ_MANAGEMENT_ALLOW_WEB_ACCESS: true
    volumes:
      - pubsub_data:/bitnami/rabbitmq
    healthcheck:
      test: rabbitmq-diagnostics -q status
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-proxy
  
volumes:
  pubsub_data:

networks:
  traefik-proxy:
    external: true

So nothing out of the ordinary, the traefik-proxy network is for the proxy. And this is the dynamic configuration for Traefik:
http:
  routers:
    pubsub-mgmt:
      rule: "Host(`pubsub.example.com`)"
      entrypoints: 
        - http
      service: "pubsub-mgmt"

    pubsub-mgmt-secure:
      entryPoints:
        - https
      rule: "Host(`pubsub.example.com`)"
      service: "pubsub-mgmt"
      tls:
        certResolver: http

  services:
    pubsub-mgmt:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://pubsub:15672"

  middlewares:
    pubsub_https_redirect:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https

tcp:
  routers:
    pubsub-amqp:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      service: "pubsub-amqp"
      entryPoints:
        - "amqp"

    pubsub-amqps:
      rule: "HostSNI(`*`)"
      service: "pubsub-amqps"
      entryPoints:
        - "amqps"
      tls:
        certResolver: http

  services:
    pubsub-amqp:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: "pubsub:5672"

    pubsub-amqps:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - address: "pubsub:5671"

The firewall on the server is turned off to make sure that it doesn't interfere with the connection.
With this configuration I can connect to the UI of RabbitMQ at pubsub.example.com.
RabbitMQ has been confirmed that is running, doing this from inside the docker container:
root@24d3da59ebaf:/# telnet localhost 5672
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
HELO

AMQP    Connection closed by foreign host

The UI of Traefik shows that the TCP ports 5671 and 5672 are configured with entrypoints amqps and amqp.
When I try to test the connection with telnet pubsub.example.com 5672 I get
Trying x.x.x.174...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused

I updated the docker-compose.yml file to have port mapping from 5672:5672 and with that, I could connect to the service with telnet. So RabbitMQ is running correctly and can be connected when bypassing Traefik. But I want to have it work without this port mapping.
I get the same error with firewall on and off. I don't know what's wrong with the setup. Do the settings look right for Traefik or am I missing something?

So I did mention "But I want to have it work without this port mapping.". What I meant I don't want to use this mapping on the RabbitMQ container, since then it bypasses the Traefik.
So dumb me forgot to add port mapping to the Traefik docker-compose file. Added the port mapping 5672:5762 to the docker-compose.yml of Traefik and I can connect over telnet to the server.
